# Unity app not showing fully in Hololens emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

Whenever I run a Unity app in the Hololens emulator, this one does not shows up fully on the emulator, when I drag an object (for example), I always hit the "end" of the Unity app frame, like it's being executed in a windows, where I need it full screen:

[image: Hololens Emulator issue]

Any idea on how can I get it to load on the whole emulator area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is the field of view of the emulator.  The Hololens has a limited field of view and to emulate that field  of view you will not see your objects outside of the bounds of that field of view in the emulator.

Comment: So, it's "normal" to see it that way? if so, that's fine, I just thought I had something setup incorrectly in either the Unity app or the emulator. Thanks!

Comment: It's normal and is emulating the real field of view you would see using the Hololens.  As you scan a scene with a real Hololens the holograms disappear when they are outside of the field of view.  The current field of view is 35 degrees by the way and the Hololens 2, expected to be announced this Monday in Barcelona, is supposed to double it to 70 degrees.